# Corona: Attempt to concatenate global 'sceneName'

Tags: lua, storyboard, coronasdk, scene

I have this code:

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard"

local options =
{
    effect = "slideLeft",
    time = 800
}

storyboard.gotoScene( "scene1", options )
```

In the same directory I have a file named "scene1.lua", but console reports this error:

```
attempt to concatenate global 'sceneName' (a nil value) in function 'gotoScene'
```

Any idea because happen this? Thanks

Comment: How we can say what's wrong with .gotoScene when you didn't post its source code?

Comment: This is all code of file (main.lua)

Comment: We would need to see the source code for the gotoScene function to be able to understand the error message completely. If I would have to guess perhaps you need to add a sceneName property to the options?

Comment: See http://developer.coronalabs.com/reference/index/storyboardgotoscene.

Comment: missngno: in tutorials, this is all code for gotoScene
lhf: like you can see, I've the same code of this reference page

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution:

In scene1.lua must be have the following methods and eventListeners:

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

function scene:createScene( event )

end

function scene:enterScene( event )

end

function scene:exitScene( event )

end

function scene:destroyScene( event )

end

scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

return scene
```

Answer (score 11):

You were just missing

```
return scene
```

in your scene1.lua file.  Scene functions are all optional.